# Why does my variable $userstr seem to have only the value "()"?

Tags: php, html, session

In my `header.php` file, at line 10 I have assigned the value of `$user = $_SESSION['user'];` and two lines after I have assigned the value of `$userstr = " $user";`

However when the `$userstr` variable is called in the HTML echo statement (at line 15) in the `<title>` and `<div class='appname'>`, all that is shown are parenthases and not the value of `$user = $_SESSION['user']`

Basically in the `<title>` and `<div>` it is showing what looks like it would be the value of `$userstr = "()"`

This is happening not only on this php file but across all the pages in the project.

Why is this?

```
<?php //header.php
$n = "\n";
session_start();
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>$n<html>$n<head>$n<script type='text/javascript' src='OSC.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='ajaxrequest.js'></script>$n";
include 'functions.php';

$userstr = ' (Guest)';

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    $loggedin = TRUE;
    $userstr = " $user";
} else $loggedin = FALSE;

echo "<title>$appname$userstr</title>$n" .
     "<link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css' type='text/css' />" .
     "</head>$n<body>$n<div class='appname'>$appname$userstr</div>";

if ($loggedin) {

    echo "</br><ul class='menu'>" .
         "<li><a href='members.php?view=$user'>Home</a></li>" .
         "<li><a href='members.php'>Members</a></li>" .
         "<li><a href='friends.php'>Friends</a></li>" .
         "<li><a href='messages.php'>Messages</a></li>" .
         "<li><a href='profile.php'>Edit Profile</a></li>" .
         "<li><a href='logout.php'>Log out</a></li></ul></br>";

} else {

    echo "</br><ul class='menu'>" .
         "<li><a href='index.php'>Home</a></li>" .
         "<li><a href='signup.php'>Sign Up</a></li>" .
         "<li><a href='login.php'>Log In</a></li></ul></br>" .
         "<span class='info'>&#8658; You must be logged in to " .
         "view this page.</span></br></br>";
}
?>
```

The `$_SESSION['user']` is defined in a separate file `login.php` at line 33 after the HTML echo statement

```
<?php // login.php
include_once 'header.php';
echo "<div class='main'><h3>Please enter your details to log in.</h3>";
$error = $user = $pass = "";

if (isset($_POST['user']) &&
    isset($_POST['pass'])) {

    $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
    $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);
    $pretoken = md5($pass);
    $token = md5($pretoken);
    $query = mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT user,pass FROM members WHERE user ='$user' AND pass='$token'"));

    if ($user = "" || $pass == "") {

        $error = "Not all fields were entered.</br>";
    } else {

        if (!$query) {
            echo <<<END_
<form method='post' action='login.php'>$error
<span class='fieldname'>Username</span>
<input type='text' maxlength='16' name='user'/></br>
<span class='fieldname'>Password</span>
<input type='text' maxlength='16' name='pass'/></br>
<span class='fieldname'>&nbsp;</span>
<input type='submit' value='Log In' />
</form></br></div></body></html>
END_;
            $error = "<span class='error'>Username/Password invalid</span></br></br>";
        } else {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
                $_SESSION['pass'] = $token;
                /*die("You are now logged in. Please <a href='members.php?view=$user'>" . "click here</a> to continue.</br></br>");*/
                header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
} elseif (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    echo "You are already logged in.";
} else {
echo <<<END_
<form method='post' action='login.php'>$error
<span class='fieldname'>Username</span>
<input type='text' maxlength='16' name='user'/></br>
<span class='fieldname'>Password</span>
<input type='password' maxlength='16' name='pass'/></br>
<span class='fieldname'>&nbsp;</span>
<input type='submit' value='Log In' />
</form></br></div></body></html>
END_;
}
?>
```

Comment: Does value in `$_SESSION['user']` really exists ?

Comment: remove the quotes $userstr = " $user";

Comment: Try taking out the quotes in `$userstr = " $user";` --- `$userstr = $user;` and this `$userstr = ' (Guest)';` should be wrapped in double quotes if you want the `()` to show as a string. `$userstr = " (Guest)";`

Comment: Try `var_dump($user)` and see what it shows.

Comment: Where do you define `$_SESSION['user']`?

Comment: @Rikesh The session does exists otherwise I would be prompted to login as the same statement that this problem is occuring in is returning a value of `$loggedin = TRUE;` which at line 21 echo's a different selection of links for the `<ul class='menu'>`

I have tried the example you offered in your answer below and now it is displaying the value of `$userstr = ' (Guest') at line 7 which confuses me as the value of $logged in is returned as true.

Comment: @JeremyMiller I have added the code for the login.php file where the `$_SESSION['user']` is defined.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried, no difference.The `$userstr` is now echoing the string " (Guest)" due to me adding the if statement `if(!empty($user)) $userstr = $user;`

This confuses me as if the `$_SESSION['user']` was not set, the value of `$loggedin` would be FALSE and prompt me to log in again.

Comment: Can you give me a quick rundown as to the expected results (maybe in an edit/question)? @MunkyMead Plus, I suggest you find another login method using a different password storage method and `mysqli_*` or PDO. What you're using now, is not safe to use.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's nothing major, all I would like to happen is for the username to appear in the `<title>` and `<div class='appname'>` in the echo statements.

As I would like to be able to call this variable `$userstr` up across other pages where the header.php file has been included.

Comment: I'd start by looking at `if ($user = "" || $pass == "") {` where there's a missing `=`

Comment: @JeremyMiller All of that works fine as later on in the statement the entries are added to the database.

The $_SESSION['user'] is set otherwise I would be prompted to log in again.

The only problem is that the variable $user is being returned as FALSE which confuses me because it's value `$user = $_SESSION['user']` is already checked to see if it isset in the previous line.

Comment: Have you tried changing `$userstr = " $user";` to `$userstr = $user;` ? @MunkyMead

Comment: As is stands in testing to a certain extent, I am getting an echo as `(Guest)` in the title and the div. Is that what you want to achieve? @MunkyMead EDIT: scratch that. Seems you found your answer.

Comment: @JeremyMiller You'll have my blessing if you post it as an answer. Good catch ;-) and I did +1 your comment about that. Just try to add a bit of "meat" to your answer, if you do put one in.

Comment: Now that, to me was a huge learning curve.</br>Slightly scary as I'm now in fear of future errors as simple as that but on a bigger scale.
But thank you both for your help, very much appreciated.
@Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome, glad a solution was found. Jeremy should have put in an answer. @MunkyMead

Comment: @MunkyMead Just remember that there doesn't exist a programmer on the planet who hasn't made that very mistake at some point in their career!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Jeremy Miller <=(*credit to*), this line:

```
if ($user = "" || $pass == "")
```

The first variable `$user` is being addressed as an [`assignment operator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) `=`, while the second variable `$pass` is addressed as a [`comparison operator`](http://php.net/ternary) `==`.

Both variables should be using a comparison operator.

```
if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
```

Comment: Thanks.  I got called into a business meeting, so glad the question got marked as answered.

Comment: You're welcome and am sure that MunkyHead thanks "you". We were wondering where you went lol! The credit goes to you Jeremy. @JeremyMiller